# Why is my .dll trying to load mscorlib.dll ?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, class-library

I made a Class Library in VS2017 in .NETCoreApp 1.1,
and when I try to load the .DLL from another test project, I get the error

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'ABC, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

And in the output I see

```
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\1.1.2\mscorlib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
```

Why is it trying to load that .DLL and in case it is required to run (but not build?), why is it not already there?

Comment: Keep looking, no error here.  It's perfectly normal to need mscorlib.dll, and missing a PDB is not fatal (and the message lets you know that the DLL did load).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is it trying to load that .DLL?

Everything loads core CLR. That's where types like "int" are defined: the *core* types that are *always* required.

> why is it not already there?

It is. The core lib is loading successfully. The message is that the debugging information isn't available. PDB files contain information that helps the debugger understand the information in the DLL. If you want the debugging information, install the debugging information.

The other assembly is failing to load for some other reason. Use the fusion log viewer to figure out why.

Comment: Visual Studio really needs to display the fusion log data (and allow configuring the logging)

Comment: @BenVoigt: I know, right? This has always bugged me too.

Comment: Hi Eric, thank you for explaining my main questions, it really helps. 
I am looking through the fusion logs, but what exactly should I look for?